# iPad autoresizingMask creating bottom margin

Tags: ipad, ios

```
LiveStreamTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 960)];
LiveStreamTable.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:LiveStreamTable];
```

This code is in viewDidLoad. In between viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear the table is resized to 916 height leaving 44 empty px at the bottom (this is in portrait mode). I know it's in between from printing debug info.

The view has a status bar and a nav bar at the top, so 960 should fill up the whole screen just right. And it does with the autoresizingMask line commented out. I only want autoresizingMask to affect it when the iPad is rotated so that landscape mode works.

I'm also having a problem where if I go to the screen in landscape in the first place then it gets sized wrong. It ends up a little too wide and too short. I assume that's related.

How do I use autoresizingMask correctly so that my table will take up the whole view (except status and nav bars) in both portrait and landscape?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your autoresizing mask is correct, but the way you init the frame is not.

Consider if this view is opened in landscape, frame (0, 0, 768, 960) yield the wrong frame.

instead of

```
LiveStreamTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 960)];
```

you should try

```
LiveStreamTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
```

This will initialize the frame according to your current ViewController's view.

I hope this help.